# Poisson Expected value using power series

Tags: power-series, exponential-function, poisson-distribution

The general calculation for the expected value of Poisson is clear to me.

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty x*\frac{(\lambda^{x}*e^{-\lambda})}{x!} =...= \lambda$$

Generally proofs declare as their first step that $x=0$ results in a zero term, therefore the above can be written as:

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty x*\frac{(\lambda^{x}*e^{-\lambda})}{x!} $$

Can't I simply leave x going from zero to $\infty$? My intuitive approach would have been:

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty x*\frac{(\lambda^{x}*e^{-\lambda})}{x!} =e^{-\lambda}*\sum_{x=0}^\infty x*\frac{(\lambda^{x})}{x!} $$

Using the power series I can then proceed to:

$$e^{-\lambda}*\sum_{x=0}^\infty x*e^\lambda  = \sum_{x=0}^\infty x $$

I definitely made a mistake somewhere along the way because the above is not $\lambda$. However, I'm not sure at what stages my thinking went wrong. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It went wrong in going from $\sum_{x=0}^\infty x \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$ to $\sum_{x=0}^\infty x e^\lambda$.  I don't know why you would think this is the case. $e^\lambda$ is not $\lambda^x/x!$, it's the sum of that from $x=0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Robert. It was my understanding that: $$e^x = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$. Is that not correct?

Comment: That is correct.  But it does not mean you can replace $\lambda^x/x!$ by $e^\lambda$ in your sum.

Comment: Ohh I see! I was treating $$\sum_{x=0}^\infty x*\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$ being the same as $$\sum_{x=0}^\infty x* \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$. This can't be the case due to the multiplication within the sum. If you post your comment as answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment posted as answer, as requested:

It went wrong in going from $\sum_{x=0}^\infty x \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$
to $\sum_{x=0}^\infty x e^\lambda$. I don't know why you would think this is the case. $e^\lambda$ is not $\lambda x/x!$, it's the sum of that from $x=0$ to $\infty$.